# Google Calendar Not Sending Email RSVP to My ICS File

Tags: icalendar

I am attempting to send a meeting invite to both a user using outlook and a user using google calendar. In both cases, the ICS is recognized as a valid meeting request. In both cases I see the "accept/yes", "tentative/maybe", "decline/no" buttons as expected.

When the recipient clicks one of these buttons in Outlook, I receive the RSVP email back to me as expected and the event is added to the Outlook user's calendar (also as expected).

HOWEVER, when the google calendar recipient clicks on one of these buttons the event IS inserted into his/her calendar BUT no RSVP email is ever sent back to me.

NOTE: I am including a SENT-BY on the organizer but simplifying this does not change the problem.

The ICS file is as follows:

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
VERSION:2.0
PRODID:-//My oncall calendar application//test.com
METHOD:REQUEST
BEGIN:VTIMEZONE
TZID:America/New_York
BEGIN:STANDARD
DTSTART;VALUE=DATE-TIME:20181104T020000
TZOFFSETFROM:-0400
TZOFFSETTO:-0500
END:STANDARD
BEGIN:DAYLIGHT
DTSTART;VALUE=DATE-TIME:20180311T020000
TZOFFSETFROM:-0500
TZOFFSETTO:-0400
END:DAYLIGHT
END:VTIMEZONE
BEGIN:VEVENT
SUMMARY:Meeting Time!
DTSTART;TZID=America/New_York;VALUE=DATE-TIME:20181022T142300
DTEND;TZID=America/New_York;VALUE=DATE-TIME:20181022T152300
DTSTAMP;VALUE=DATE-TIME:20181022T182300Z
UID:0.8860563089422712
SEQUENCE:0
ATTENDEE;PARTSTAT=NEEDS-ACTION;RSVP=TRUE;ROLE=REQ-PARTICIPANT:outlook_user@corpville.com
ATTENDEE;PARTSTAT=NEEDS-ACTION;RSVP=TRUE;ROLE=REQ-PARTICIPANT:gmail_user@gmail.com
CLASS:PUBLIC
CREATED;VALUE=DATE-TIME:20181003T115542Z
DESCRIPTION:Go online to update.
LOCATION:my desk
ORGANIZER;SENT-BY="mailto:no-reply@somewhereelse.io":MAILTO:me@example.com
PRIORITY:5
STATUS:CONFIRMED
BEGIN:VALARM
ACTION:DISPLAY
DESCRIPTION:Reminder
TRIGGER;RELATED=START:-PT1H
END:VALARM
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
```

The email msg is here:

```
Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary="===============8900875677198681530=="
MIME-Version: 1.0
Subject: Meeting Time!
From: My Mailer <no-reply@somewhereelse.io>
reply-to: me@example.com
To: outlook_user@corpville.com,gmail_user@gmail.com

--===============8900875677198681530==
Content-Type: text/plain; charset="us-ascii"
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

Go online to update.
--===============8900875677198681530==
Content-Type: text/calendar; method="REQUEST"; name="invite.ics"; charset="UTF-8"
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
Content-Description: invite.ics
Filename: invite.ics
Path: invite.ics
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--===============8900875677198681530==--
```

Answer (score 6):

We also had the problem that Google Calendar does not send event invitation responses (RSVPs) to the inviting person from Microsoft Outlook/Exchange.

In our case, we discovered that all of the **affected Outlook accounts have corresponding Google accounts associated with them**, which are using the same email addresses as the Google accounts; i.e., registered on Google using the company's email address instead of a GMail address.  GMail is not enabled for those accounts.

Google Calendar seems to be processing the responses from Google Calendar directly or internally, and does not send or forward the regular RSVP email response to the external / company email address.

We will check now

1. whether Google Calendar can be disabled for those Google accounts
2. whether Google Calendar has a setting to not mute/eat the RSVP responses or send CCs in all cases
3. whether enabling GMail for those Google accounts resolves the problem.

Comment: I can confirm that this is the cause of the issue. I sent invites from Fastmail to (an unrelated) Gmail account and got no RSVP back. I then changed the email associated with my google account, and now Gmail does send RSVPs to Fastmail account.

Answer (score 4):

OK. I found my error. If you are using a GMail based email address for the organizer, it appears that Google Calendar will not send a RSVP reply unless it verifies that the email address did in fact create the google calendar. If you use an arbitrary email address (that you own, for example) then it sends it back no problem.

Comment: Can you elaborate on this? Do you mean that my Google account is missing a confirmation in Google Calendar somewhere? The whole problem scenario sounds very similar to https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/2200781-not-receiving-meeting-responses-from-gmail-addresses, but there is no solution.

Comment: We just learned that Outlook does receive a RSVP response from GMail, if the meeting is created/organized from a different, shared email calendar address in Exchange instead of the personal account.

Comment: @KeytonWeissinger I don't understand what your solution here is, can you detail a little bit better? I'm facing the same issue and I'm not being able to receive RSVP emails on the Gmail address.

Answer (score 0):

The can happen when the inviter's email address is associated with a Google Workspace Account and the invitee is using Gmail (regardless if it's personal or via Google Workspace). In this case, Google will prefer to internally process the RSVP (rather than send it out through the Internet) which then ends up in the wrong place.

In my case, because I (the inviter) no longer use Google Workspace for email and calendar, I simply turned off my Google Workspace account's Gmail and Calendar apps via `admin.google.com > Apps > Google Workspace > Service Status`.

After doing this, all RSVPs from all invitees (including invitees using Gmail), started making their way back to my non-Google-hosted calendar app.